# C# - Multi Values of an input string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

**I Have an input  text  :**

```
string DefaultInput = "Name : John | FamilyName : Doe |";
```

**I Want to be able to Extract the "John" & "Doe" and maybe other values from 1 input using Regex**

My Code :

```
Match m = Regex.Match(DefaultInput,"Name : (.*?) | FamilyName : (.*?) |");
this.textBox1.Text = "ProfileName : " + m.Groups[1].Value + "\r\nProfileFamilyName : " + m.Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: are you limited to only regex ?

Comment: unfortunately yes ! I need to learn using that for some home works :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to escape regex alternative character `|` with `\`, because it is a part of its syntax:

```cs
Match m = Regex.Match(DefaultInput, "Name : (.*?) \\| FamilyName : (.*?) \\|");
```

and the code works.